# How to call the next ID stored in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently creating a posting system where users are able to post. When users view a post, they would be able to go to the next post which is the "nextpost" button.

```
nextpost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextpost);
nextpost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                post = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseDatabase.class);
                checkpostid = marker.getSnippet();  
                checkpostid += 1;   
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                                  "" + checkpostid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ViewPostDetails();
            }

            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            };
        };
        mDatabaseComPostRef.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

"checkpostid" checks the current ID of the post but I haven't been able to increment it and go to the next ID.

In our database screenshot for example, in table "`Post`", let's assume the  current post is "`KcY8F7H-jW_4sW4FoKP`". Once the user taps the "`nextpost`" button, it should call the next ID which would be "`KcY8LxewB_SSKl-HYkW`" in the Firebase database.

**Link to a screenshot of our database:**

[image]

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to also store the generated ids in another collection named PostId. So you can easily do what you need.

Comment: What do you mean? Make an array?

Comment: Yes! A id´s array.

Comment: So I'd have to put all saved IDs in an array? What if a user creates a new post? Is there a way to directly call the next element in Firebase?

Comment: Can you tell me how to import all Firebase IDs into an array?